# Solving this kata from codewars ,any tips/fixing ? (new to python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, helper

So i have this kata:
In this simple assignment you are given a number and have to make it negative. But maybe the number is already negative?

Example:

```py
make_negative(1)   # return -1
make_negative(-5)  # return -5
make_negative(0)   # return 0
```

and i tried solving it with:

```py
def make_negative(number):
    if number > 0:
        number * -1
    elif number < 0:
        pass
    return number
```

and the result i get is ( Passed: 2Failed: 1Exit Code: 1 ) the failed one says (42 should equal -42)

Real question is , what did i do wrong ? and if some1 can help me solve this ? ^^

Comment: The line `number * -1` does nothing. The result is neither returned, assigned to a variable or used in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```py
def make_negative(num):
    if num > 0:
        return num * (-1)
    elif num < 0: 
        return num
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This Also Works:

```
if (num > 0){
return num * -1
}else {
return num;
}
```

or

```
return num > 0 ? num * -1 : num;
```

Comment: Why the `num =` in the middle there? It should just be `num * -1` in both of your solutions, not `num = num * -1`.

Comment: @joanis Yes thank you very much I've rectified it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def make_negative( number ):
    if number < 0 or number==0:
        return number
    elif number > 0:
        return (number - (2*number))
```